# Cannot run my script from rc.local file as a different user

Tags: boot, user

I have a script which runs my program and I would like to run it automatically when my pi has booted. The script is rather simple as:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
sleep 2
cd /home/pi/
/home/pi/monitor
```

I have added it to my `rc.local` file as:

```
/home/pi/monitorscript.sh &
```

The issue is that this is run as `root`. Now, is it possible to run this in the environment of the `pi` user i.e. with all the environment variables (as defined in `.bashrc`) all correctly setup?

Comment: It's good practice when writing scripts to have them setup their own working environment either by the use of a config file or by defining the environment variables at the start of the script and then setting them further down.  This makes them much more portable. requiring only a config file edit or edit of a few variables at the start of the script should you copy it to a different machine or run for another user.

Comment: I ended up doing that. Exported the variables that I needed into the `monitorscript.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I added:

```
cd /home/pi
su pi -c /home/pi/monitorscript.sh &
```

This ensured everything runs fine and in the correct user space.